# redis losing keys when inserting with call_user_func_array

Tags: redis

I am trying to push 10K elements into an array and try to add them to redis set using call_user_func_array, but I get a very strange result.

This is the code:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1',6380);

$list_id=0;

$test_ar = array();
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++){
  $test_ar[]=rand(1,4);  
}


echo "test array cnt: ".count($test_ar)." \n";


array_unshift($test_ar, 'test:'.$list_id);

echo "array chunk: ".print_r(array_slice($test_ar, 0, 10),true)." \n";

call_user_func_array(array($redis, 'sAdd'), $test_ar);


$test_cnt = $redis->scard('test:'.$list_id);


echo "test_cnt : $test_cnt \n";
```

this is the output:

```
test array cnt: 10000
array chunk: Array
(
    [0] => test:0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 4
)

test_cnt : 4
```

only 4 items are inserted?
It seems that the number of items inserted is related to the rand parameter. changing the rand to rand(1,10), will insert 10 items. If I remove the rand() all together and replace it with $i (so each element in the array is incremented), it works, and 10K are pushed the the redis 'test:0' set.

Any idea why is this happening?

### Update 1:

I change the random to rand(10,14), and 5 items were inserted. so it seems that it is related the range of the parameters is the rand.

### Update 2:

I change the random to:

```
$test_ar[]=(mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax())*20;
```

and all 10K items were inserted:

```
test array cnt: 10000
array chunk: Array
(
    [0] => test:0
    [1] => 4.6265427696642
    [2] => 4.6970932580051
    [3] => 13.528551176902
    [4] => 3.0136572117981
    [5] => 6.1535581602499
    [6] => 2.2943511802211
    [7] => 6.6211488128738
    [8] => 5.5308832533336
    [9] => 6.9294742527089
)

test_cnt : 10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using sadd which is adding a value to set. Set contains distinct values alone. For example in your case of rand(10,14) you have only 5 distinct values ie, 10,11,12,13,14 scard (count) of that distinct value is 5.  http://redis.io/commands/sadd

If you want to push all the elements irrespective of duplicate entries you should use list. ie. lpush or rpush commands. After pushing you can use llen to see the number of values inserted. It will be 10K. 
http://redis.io/commands/llen

Comment: Thanks! good answer. It makes perfect sense. In my main application I use set with distinct values, and I wanted to test the performance, hence I created this test case with the random, and this is where I encountered this issue. Appreciate your help.